# how to display the frame difference output of all the frames in video using matlab

Tags: matlab

I have calculated difference of h,s and v value of current and background  frame of a video and want to display the value in order to do random checkness of the difference value for further action. I got final output as 360x640 matrix. Guess it displays difference value of last frame. Can anyone help me to display all the difference value of h, s and v.

```
videoObject = VideoReader(movieFullFileName)
    % Determine how many frames there are.
%   numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
    vidHeight = videoObject.Height;
    vidWidth = videoObject.Width;
for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames
        % Extract the frame from the movie structure.
        thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);
% Now let's do the differencing
        alpha = 0.5;
        if frame == 1
            Background = thisFrame;
        else
            % Change background slightly at each frame
            %           Background(t+1)=(1-alpha)*I+alpha*Background
            Background = (1-alpha)* thisFrame + alpha * Background;
        end
        % Display the changing/adapting background.
        subplot(2, 2, 3);
        imshow(Background);
        title('Adaptive Background', 'FontSize', fontSize);
        % Do color conversion from rgb to hsv
        x=rgb2hsv(thisFrame);
        y=rgb2hsv(Background);
        % Split the hsv component to h,s,v value
        Hx = x(:,:,1);
        Sx = x(:,:,2);
        Vx = x(:,:,3);
        Hy = y(:,:,1);
        Sy = y(:,:,2);
        Vy = y(:,:,3);
        dh=(abs(double(Hx) - double(Hy)));
        ds1=(abs(double(Sx) - double(Sy)));
        dv1=(abs(double(Vx) - double(Vy)));
        disp(dh);
        disp(ds1);
        disp(dv1);
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to show three images with h,s and v value? What is your desired output?

Comment: @AndreaPerissinotto My desired output is to calculate and display the difference of 'h' ,'s' and 'v' value of current and background frame of all the frames in a video.

Comment: Weel, I think you've already calculate the difference  dh=(abs(double(Hx) - double(Hy)));, so you just need to display it right?

Comment: @AndreaPerissinotto Yes, is it possible to view the difference output  (h,s,v) of every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to show the complete image**

First you need to evaluate the full HSV image

```
hsv=zeros(size(x,1),size(x,2))

hsv(:,:,1) = dh;
hsv(:,:,2) = ds1;
hsv(:,:,3) = dv1;
```

then convert to RGB using:

```
rgb = hsv2rgb(hsv);
```

then you can show it using:

```
image(rgb);
```

**If you want to show single h,s and v image**

just use:

```
for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames

    subplot(3,1,1)
    imshow(dh)
    subplot(3,1,2)
    imshow(ds1)
    subplot(3,1,3)
    imshow(ds2)
    impixelinfo;
    pause;

end
```

You will see the pixel value on the bottom left part of the image, when the cursor is above the image.
To continue with the next image press any keyboard key

Answer (score 0):

You should add `drawnow` at the end of the `for`-loop to update the figure window every frame.

Moreover, `disp` will show you the difference matrices as numbers. Consider using something like

```
subplot(2, 2, 1)
imshow(dh)
```

with proper color scaling to visualize the difference matrices.

Comment: I got the difference output. my doubt is whether it shows the only final frame difference output?

Comment: Yes it does. If you want see each result inside the for cycle you can generate a figure for each iteration (see my answer). Otherwise you can put a: "pause" after the plot . This will wait for the user to press a keyboard key before continue, so you have the time to see your output.

Comment: @AndreaPerissinotto thank you. but I want to view the output of each iteration in order to check the pixel value close to zero or not. How will it be possible?

Comment: if you add "impixelinfo" command before the pause you can see the pixel value when you hover above the image. See my edit answer